# How to supply a value of type Int64 to a Generic type if it's known to be Int64?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using the following method.

```
public static Generic Get<Generic>(this object self)
{
  try { return (Generic)self; }
  catch (Exception) { return default(Generic); }
}
```

A new requirement says that if a *Int64* is *null* it needs to be mapped to *-13*. I've tried to approach it by returning said fix value if the type is *Int64* like so.

```
public static Generic Get<Generic>(this object self)
{
  if (self == null && typeof (Generic) == typeof (long))
    return -13;

  try { return (Generic)self; }
  catch (Exception) { return default(Generic); }
}
```

However, the compiler disagrees with me because it worries that I'll be returning *-13* when the *Generic* type is incompatible with said value. How do I resolve it?

I tried googling for custom default values but got nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can box it to `object` first:

```
return (Generic)(object)-13;
```

Then you'll have a chain of two conversions that are acceptable at compile time.

Comment: Is there no other way? The cast-casting seems so ugly... I can live with it but I want to know if it's a work-around or **the** way to go.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I personally haven't found another way that doesn't boil down to this. If you want to avoid the double casting only syntactically, then you can create an `object` local variable at the top, assign your numbers to that and return the value of that variable later (casting it to `Generic`, first). But I'm not sure there's a way to actually avoid the double conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
public static Generic Get<Generic>(this object self)
{
    return
        self == null && typeof(long) == typeof(Generic)
        ? (Generic)(object)-13L 
        : (Generic)self;
}
```

Given the extended requirement of multiple types then this works:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Delegate> map = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>()
{
    { typeof(long), (Func<object, long>)(o => o == null ? -13 : (long)o) },
    { typeof(float), (Func<object, float>)(o => o == null ? -13.0f : (float)o) },
    { typeof(double), (Func<object, double>)(o => o == null ? -13.0 : (double)o) },
};

public static Generic Get<Generic>(this object self)
{
    return
        map.ContainsKey(typeof(Generic))
            ? ((Func<object, Generic>)(map[typeof(Generic)]))(self)
            : (Generic)self;
}
```

Comment: I lied a little bit. The requirement is actually for *long* and *float*. Possibly even *double*. Will I have to build three (or more!) return statements or can I generalize the inner thingy not to have the suffix *L*?

Comment: You need to check in the condition for the three types.

Comment: @oussamaabdou How about the approach suggested by Theodoros?

Comment: Its correct to it's the same approach of @Enigmativity

Comment: @oussamaabdou Oh, now that I read your comment again, I realize that I misinterpreted the first time. You don't mean three conditional statements with each return. You mean a single conditional statement with three conditions in it connected by a disjungation), right?

Comment: @KonradViltersten - I've added an extended answer that even (apparently) avoids the `(object)` boxing - although it doesn't really.

Comment: Yes this exactly what i mean :)